# Unknown CSS within my websites CSS file

Tags: css, html

I have a few CSS statements in my website, which I have not been able to decipher or find any reference on the search engines. Could anyone please check and inform if these are valid CSS or just something some tool has spewed out and can be safely removed?

I am referring to the `{{` `}}` statements. Each has a `settings . abc-def-xyz`, which I am also unable to understand.

```
.main-footer .connect > li {
    width: 32.3333%;
    height: 185px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid {{
        settings . primary-border-colour
    }};
    text-align: center;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    * vertical-align: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    * display: inline;
}


@media (max-width: 719px) {
    .main-footer .connect > li {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: auto;
        border-left: none;
        border-top: 1px solid {{ settings . primary-border-colour }};
        padding: 0 0 45px;
    }

    .main-footer .connect > li.first {
        border-top: none;
    }
}

.main-footer .connect .title {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #bbbbbb;
    margin: 40px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: {{
        settings . light-text-colour
    }};
}

.main-footer .sub-footer p {
    font-family: {{
        settings . secondary-header-font
    }};
    font-size: 12px;
    color: {{
        settings . lightest-text-colour
    }};
    text-align: center;
    margin: 50px 0 30px;
}


.main-footer .sub-footer p a {
    color: {{
        settings . theme-detail-link-colour
    }};
}

.main-footer .sub-footer p a:hover {
    color: {{
        settings . theme-detail-link-hover-colour
    }};
}
```

Comment: `{{ }}` looks like output from a preprocessor. It should not be in the published stylesheet.

Comment: That's not valid CSS - the braces are pure nonsense. It looks like some form of *template* used to read in settings, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with this.

It was being generated by the tool we were using to create the HTML and that used to create links to templates which were default to the tool and had already been incorporated when the tool starts.

We have made the required configuration changes to the tool to produce HTML and CSS, which conforms to an actual CSS element, instead of what the tool was producing.